# Find angle in rad from sin

Tags: trigonometry

I can't solve this and I have a test tomorrow, can you help me please:

$\alpha - \beta = \frac{3}{5} + \pi$

$\cos \alpha = \frac{1}{3}$

Determine $\sin\alpha - \beta$

That's the problem. Here's what I know:

$\sin \alpha = (\sqrt 24) / 5$

How do I progress? Thanks for the help.

Comment: What's $sen$? Do you mean $\sin$?

Comment: Do you mean $\sin$ ? what is $sen$ ?

Comment: Shouldn't $\sin \alpha = \frac{2\sqrt2}{3}$ ?

Comment: How did you get that? I got this value from Pythagoras' theorem, unless I did something wrong.

Comment: $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$

Comment: Alright, you're right, I guess the method I used is wrong. But how do I progress from there?

Comment: am not quite sure, how the answer should look like. $\beta$ can be calculated in terms of $\alpha$ by using $\alpha =\cos^{-1} \frac{1}{3}$ There was a typo in prev comment and I am unable to edit it.

Comment: I think you could just substitute value for $\alpha$ from first equation into second one to get an expression in terms of arccos for $\beta$..

Comment: I think this question is sufficiently vague and internally inconsistent (the sine and cosine of to be voted down and even close-voted. I find it puzzling why there were actually 2 upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

$$\alpha - \beta = \frac{3}{5} + \pi$$

$$\cos \alpha = \frac{1}{3}$$

so

$$\sin\alpha=\pm\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}$$

So the answer is

$$\pm\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}-\beta$$

and because of

$$\alpha - \beta = \frac{3}{5} + \pi$$

it is
$$\beta=\alpha-\pi-\frac{3}{5}$$

substituting to

$$\pm\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}-\beta$$

;

$$\pm\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}-\alpha+\pi+\frac{3}{5}$$

where

$$\cos \alpha = \frac{1}{3}$$

and

$$\alpha =2n\pi  \mp\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{3}$$

Fixing the plus-minus and minus-plus, the answer is

$$2n\pi\pm\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\mp\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{3}+\pi+\frac{3}{5}$$